# Flutter_downloader HardCrash on Android immediately after download start

Tags: flutter, flutter-android

Can anyone explain me what's going wrong. I am trying for two days but unable to solve, the app is crashing again and again. Download was working normally, but after adding a new page,just to add new download, the app crashed, and even after deleting the page also it continued crashing.

**First crash:** No information, sudden disconnect.

**Second crash:**
D/EgretLoader(28378): EgretLoader(Context context)
D/EgretLoader(28378): The context is not activity
W/WM-WorkSpec(28378): Backoff delay duration less than minimum value
D/DownloadWorker(28378): DownloadWorker{url=https://bppimt.ac.in/nu/Notice/Notice_on_Postponement_of__scheduled_examinations_on_17.03.2021.pdf,filename=Notice_on_Postponement_of__scheduled_examinations_on_17.03.2021.pdf,savedDir=/storage/emulated/0/Download,header=,isResume=false
D/DownloadWorker(28378): Update notification: {notificationId: 1, title: Notice_on_Postponement_of__scheduled_examinations_on_17.03.2021.pdf, status: 2, progress: 0}
D/DownloadWorker(28378): Open connection to https://bppimt.ac.in/nu/Notice/Notice_on_Postponement_of__scheduled_examinations_on_17.03.2021.pdf
I/com.mcd.twb(28378): Background concurrent copying GC freed 23356(1592KB) AllocSpace objects, 90(3MB) LOS objects, 49% free, 5MB/10MB, paused 19.531ms total 75.666ms
W/ContentCatcher(28378): Failed to notify a WebView
E/libEGL (28378): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
I/flutter (28378): Fatal: could not find callback
E/libEGL (28378): validate_display:92 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
I/chatty (28378): uid=10621(com.mcd.twb) RenderThread identical 3 lines
E/libEGL (28378): validate_display:92 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
F/OpenGLRenderer(28378): Failed to set damage region on surface 0x79eadeef00, error=EGL_BAD_DISPLAY
Lost connection to device.

**Rest of the crashes:**
D/DownloadWorker(32459): DownloadWorker{url=https://bppimt.ac.in/nu/Notice/Notice_on_Postponement_of__scheduled_examinations_on_17.03.2021.pdf,filename=Notice_on_Postponement_of__scheduled_examinations_on_17.03.2021.pdf,savedDir=/storage/emulated/0/Download,header=,isResume=false
D/DownloadWorker(32459): Update notification: {notificationId: 1, title: Notice_on_Postponement_of__scheduled_examinations_on_17.03.2021.pdf, status: 2, progress: 0}
D/DownloadWorker(32459): Open connection to https://bppimt.ac.in/nu/Notice/Notice_on_Postponement_of__scheduled_examinations_on_17.03.2021.pdf
I/com.mcd.twb(32459): NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 22912(1545KB) AllocSpace objects, 82(2MB) LOS objects, 49% free, 5MB/10MB, paused 116us total 227.920ms
I/flutter (32459): Fatal: could not find callback
Lost connection to device.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. The problem is finally solved, it was the problem with my code. Actually I have created the new page outside the main channel. So it was not properly initialized. Now it is working fine.

Comment: can you please provide your code?

Comment: @Zionnite please check once, https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_downloader/issues/445 
It may be solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If someone facing same issue, application get crash immediately after starting download.

Then please ensure that you've register the download callback, check it [#445](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_downloader/issues/445)

Answer (score -3):

For anybody experiencing this issue, do something like this:

```
initFlutterDownloader() async {
await FlutterDownloader.initialize(
    debug: true // optional: set false to disable printing logs to 
   console
 );
}
```

then paste this code in initState in the page you want to download the file from:

```
initFlutterDownloader();
```